# How does this Python string code work?

Tags: python

My professor showed the class some code we can use to display the initials of a name, but she never explained how it works. The textbook doesn’t help much either. I am confused only on the second line. This isn’t for homework; I just want to know what makes it display the first letters in the string.

```
userName = input("Enter your name: ")
initials = '.'.join(name[0].upper() for name in userName.split())
print(initials)
```

Comment: The second line contains string indexing, a generator expression, and calls to `str.join`, `str.upper`, and `str.split`.Which of those things are you unfamiliar with?

Comment: This code is buggy; the final initial isn't followed by a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `userName = "john paul jones"` after the input is run.

Then `userName.split()` splits the name on whitespace `' '`, returning an list which consists of the strings `"john", "paul", "jones" (in that order).

The `for name in userName.split()` part iterates over this -- hence `name` is successively bound to `"john"` then `"paul"` then `"jones"`.

When `name` is bound to e.g. `"paul"` the expression `name[0]` returns the first character (e.g. `'p'`) which is then turned to the corresponding upper case (if it isn't already upper case). The net result is that the generator expression

```
(name[0].upper() for name in userName.split())
```

successively returns the strings `'J'` then `'P'` then `'J'` (in our example).

Finally, `join` takes an iterable of strings and joins them together, using as a delimiter the string that join is called on -- in this case `'.'` -- think of this delimiter as the glue which holds the strings in the iterable together. When thus joined -- the final result is `"J.P.J"`.

Your instructor probably should have tacked on a `+'.'` at the end of the expression to get a final period (`"J.P.J."`).

Comment: Actually the final result is `J.P.J` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
userName = input("Enter your name: ")
```

First, userName is a string, for example my name: `kevin guan`.

```
'.'.join(name[0].upper() for name in userName.split())
```

Now, `name[0].upper() for name in userName.split()` is a generator comprehension(it gives a generator):

```
userName.split()
```

gives a list like `['kevin', 'guan']`.

```
name[0].upper() for name in ['Kevin', 'Guan']
```

You'll get `['K', 'G']`, because `name[0]` is `k` in first `for` loop, then [`.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) covert it to `K` and save it to a list(actually it's a generator). 
And at the second loop, we got `G`.

Then, `'.'.join` gives `K.G`. For more info, please check the document about [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [**generator comprehension**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it apart:

```
initials = '.'.join(name[0].upper() for name in userName.split())
```

There is an inner loop here, `for name in userName.split()`.  This is splitting the string in userName into chunks, or `name`s.  The documentation for [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) says:

> Return a list of the words of the string s. If the optional second
>   argument sep is absent or None, the words are separated by arbitrary
>   strings of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, return,
>   formfeed).

So if the string contains spaces, it will split the string as you would expect.  `"my lastname"` would be split into a list `["my", "lastname"]`.  This list becomes the list of names in the `for` loop.  `name` would become the values `"my"` and `"lastname"` in this case.

Next, we have the cryptic function `name[0].upper()`.  This is applied to each value of `name` from the `for` loop.  The first part, `name[0]` takes the first character of the string in `name`.  The second part, `.upper()` converts that first character (which is actually a one-characters string) into an uppercase character.  This is described in the same documentation as above.

Continuing our example, `name[0].upper()` takes the two strings `"my"` and `"lastname"`, takes the first letter from each one and converts it to uppercase: `"M"` and `"L"`.  The resulting list is `["M", "L"]`.

Finally, the `'.'.join()` expression takes the list inside of the `join()` and joins them together using the `'.'` character.  In this case, the result is `"M.L"`.